# Search special characters in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, special-characters, kibana

I have ELK 6.8.1 version for log analysis. Now I need to search some strings via the Kibana search bar. 
I need to find the logs include "] ERROR (". I tried:

```
message: "\] \ERROR \("
```

But nothing worked. Can anyone have experience help me with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

= && || > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ / + - are all reserved characters. 
These need to be escaped.

Try escaping them twice.

```
 message: "\\] ERROR \\("
```

Comment: I tried,doesn't work. This construction includes strings, such as ```Error``` or ```>ERROR<```